# Parse error - unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, parsing, laravel

Php complains that

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, 
expecting ')' in /home/edler2/www/blog/application/config/database.php on line 74
```

It seems plain wrong, and now I'm stuck.

../config/database.php looks like this.

```
70  'mysql' => array(
71      'driver'   => 'mysql',
72      'host'     => 'localhost',
73      'database' => 'blogtest' 
74      'username' => 'root',
75      'password' => 'xxxxx',
76      'charset'  => 'utf8',
77      'prefix'   => '',
78  ),
```

Comment: There's a missing comma after `'blogtest'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
73      'database' => 'blogtest' ,
                                 ^ this comma is missing.
```